# Playing other video formats (e.g. MKV) in QuickTime

Tags: software-recommendation, video, quicktime

I know this is a very old question, actually from the era of Perian. When I searched for this topic around the web, everything dated back to '11 and even older. Now that Perian is no longer being developed (latest version is 1.2.3) and projects based on Perian (like [this one](https://github.com/MaddTheSane/perian)) are not working either (at least in Yosemite and QuickTime Player 10.4), I thought a good wrap-up would be nice for future generations who will be seeking answers to this very question.

Here is the situation:
I have some AVI or MKV video files and I want to play them using QuickTime Player. Using other media players like VLC is not an option.

**Is there any way I could use QuickTime Player to play these files?**

I found [this link on Apple Support website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204382) but as far as I could see, those third-party software offer "players", not "components" that are supposed to add the capability to QuickTime Player.

Optional: Consider that I have some `srt` subtitle files associated with those videos and it would be super nice to be able to use the subtitles with the videos.

So, please correct me if

P.S. The title should've been "... video **container** files..." but I preferred to use the more conventional "format" instead of the confusing "container" term.

Comment: Just curious, why is using VLC not an option?

Comment: @user3439894 Main reason is, I don't like its UI. Secondly, I think playing movies using VLC consumes much more energy than playing them with QuickTime Player.

Comment: Yes, playing the same file in both, Quicktime uses ~50% less CPU and if on battery that's appreciable.  Like you I wanted to play most videos with Quicktime, not so much the power consumption issue as most of the time my MBP is docked using AC, however I never liked Quicktime with the various plugins I tried in past and so use VLC as needed.  Using the Dark Interface style made it more palatable. For me I typically do not watch many videos when on battery so the power savings is not an issue.  Hope you find and answer that's worth checking out as I wouldn't mind using Quicktime more often.